# Is there a limit on the "search for" argument in the Python replace function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python to search and replace a string in a .txt file. I need to replace the value 0.000001 (6 decimal places), the code does not replace this value but will replace 0.0001 (4 decimal places). 
Therefore, is there some limit on this input argument (see code below)?

```
a0 = 0.000001
ka = 0.1
dt = 7
an = a0+ka*dt

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data1 = f.read()
    data1 = data1.replace(str(a0), str(an), 1)

with open ('file.txt', 'w', 1) as f:
    f.write(data1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a matter of "limit", but of numeric notation:

```
>>> a0 = 0.000001
>>> print(a0)
1e-06
>>> a0 = 0.0001
>>> print(a0)
0.0001
>>>
```

The "0.000001" string read from file won't get replaced because the `replace()` method will be looking for "1e-06". The same does not occur with "0.0001".

**Format** `a0` as *float*, instead:

```
    ...
    data1 = data1.replace(str("%f" % a0), str(an), 1)
    ...
```